# how can i fetch data json from api to Web app page html

Tags: javascript, html, json

I want to fetch all Jason data into a table
How can i do that?

i write code javascript to get json data from my api, but i can't fetch all data like "category" "name" "value" to table in page html !!

**api json :**

```
[
    { "allinfo":[ 
    {
    "category": "category1",
    "info": [{
          "name": "Tech1",
          "value": "1575"
       },
       {
          "name": "tech2",
          "value": "a-25"
       }
    ]
 },
 {
    "category": "category2",
    "info": [{
          "name": "Announced",
          "value": "2022"
       },
       {
          "name": "Status",
          "value": "Coming soon"
       }
    ]
 },
 {
    "category": "category3",
    "info": [{
          "name": "with",
          "value": "163.3 cm"
       },
       {
          "name": "Weight",
          "value": "500 g"
       }
    ]
 }]
}]
```

**code javascript :**

```
$.getJSON('https://myapi', function(data) {
  console.log(data);      
  $.each(data, function(index, value) {
    console.log(value);        
    var category = value.allinfo.category;
    var name = value.allinfo.info.name;
    var value = value.allinfo.info.value;        
    $('.output').append('<div class="cont"><h3>' + category + '</h3><table><tbody><tr><td>'+ name +'</td><td>' + value + '</td></tr></tbody></table></div>');});});
```

**html :**

```
<div class="output"></div>
```

**output html:**

```
<div class="cont">
    <h3>undefined</h3>
    <table>
       <tbody>
          <tr>
             <td>undefined</td>
             <td>undefined</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>undefined</td>
            <td>undefined</td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**i want to be like this :**

```
<div class="cont">
    <h3>category1</h3>
    <table>
       <tbody>
          <tr>
             <td>Tech1</td>
             <td>1575</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>tech2</td>
            <td>a-25</td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
 <div class="cont">
    <h3>category2</h3>
    <table>
       <tbody>
          <tr>
             <td>Announced</td>
             <td>2022</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Status</td>
            <td>Coming soon</td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
 </div>
 <div class="cont">
    <h3>category3</h3>
    <table>
       <tbody>
          <tr>
             <td>with</td>
             <td>163.3 cm</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Weight</td>
            <td>500 g</td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

How can i do that?
I appreciate your help

Comment: Hi, you are not defined variable category, value, update and check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a short way of doing the whole thing in one expression:

```js
const da=[{ "allinfo":[
 {"category": "category1",
  "info":[{"name":"Tech1","value":"1575"},
          {"name":"tech2","value": "a-25"}]},
 {"category": "category2",
  "info":[{"name": "Announced","value": "2022"},
          {"name": "Status","value": "Coming soon"}]},
 {"category": "category3",
  "info":[{"name": "with","value": "163.3 cm"},
          {"name": "Weight","value": "500 g"}]}
]}];

document.querySelector("div.cont").innerHTML=da[0].allinfo.map(cat=>
 `<h1>${cat.category}</h1>
  <table><tbody>${cat.info.map(r=>
  `<tr><td>${r.name}</td><td>${r.value}</td></tr>`).join("")}
  </tbody></table>`).join("\n")
```

```css
td {border:1px solid grey; width:100px}
table{border-collapse:collapse}
```

```html
<div class="cont"></div>
```

There are two (nested) `.map()`s looping over

- `da[0].categories` for all tables using `cat` for each category and
- `cat.info` for all records `r` in one category

The output of each `map()` is `.join()`-ed and the resulting string is assigned to the first encountered `div.cont`'s `.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0):

You can access your Obj properties like this:

To get category:

```
var cat = value[0].allinfo[1].category
console.log(cat) //category2
```

To get info:

```
var name = value[0].allinfo[1].info[0].name
console.log(name) //announced
```

**Pay attention:** to your variable names, it appears that you name all variables as "name"!

Comment: @Taric_Ov can i fetch all category, name and value without doing this `value[i].allinfo[i].category` every time, because json have a lot of categories ?

Comment: It seems that your JSON is pretty consistent regarding the level where "category, name, value" live in the JSON tree, if so, you could iterate over the root selector and push similar property values to one array, as follows:


`let data = value[0].allinfo;`

`let cats = [];`
`let vals = [];`
`let names = [];`

`data.forEach(i => catts.push(i.category));`
`data.forEach(i => vals.push(i.info[0].value));`
`data.forEach(i => names.push(i.info[0].name));`

`console.log(cats) //['category1', 'category2', 'category3']`


*If this solves your question, kindly let me know.*